# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2021-08-22 19:30:00+01:00'

Tags: python, valueerror

Im trying to run the following code but im getting a value error for a value that is not in the list mentioned. The code is mentioned below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import dateutil



fig, axes=plt.subplots(2,1,squeeze=False)
def animate(i):
    datafileprice=open('data_close_price.txt', 'r')
    dataprice=datafileprice.readlines()
    datafileprice.close()          
    
    datafiledate=open('data_date_volume.txt', 'r')
    datadate=datafiledate.readlines()
    datafiledate.close()  
        
    seperated=""
    seperated+=datadate[0]
    seperatedlst=seperated.split("&&")
    volumelst=seperatedlst[1].split(",")
    datelst=seperatedlst[0].split(",")
    lvolume=[]
    ldate=[]

    for i in range(1,len(volumelst)-1):
        lvolume.append(float(volumelst[i]))
        
    for i in range(len(datelst)-2):
        ldate.append(datelst[i])
#---------------------------------------------------------------
    priceplot=""
    priceplot+=dataprice[0]
    plotprice=priceplot.split(",")
    
    lprice=[]
    for i in range(len(plotprice)-1):
        lprice.append(float(plotprice[i]))

    
    fig, axes=plt.subplots(2,1,squeeze=False)
    
    dates=[dateutil.parser.parse(s) for s in ldate]
    
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
    
    ax=plt.gca()
    ax.set_xticks(dates)
    xfmt=md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
    axes[1][0].plot(dates, lprice)
    axes[0][0].plot(dates, lvolume)
    plt.title('Stock of InterGlobe Aviation')


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,interval=10000)
plt.show()
```

the file data_date_volume has both the date and volume values which have then been seperated but the error still appears.
the error is:

```
lvolume.append(float(volumelst[i]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2021-08-22 19:30:00+01:00'
```

Comment: Why do you read the entire file if you're just using the first line?

Comment: You try to convert a string that represents date to float. It can't work.

Comment: A string cannot be converted to a float the way you try to do this. First you need to parse the string and convert it to seconds or miliseconds from the epoch, then append to lvolume. Time module can be helpful.

Comment: You're obviously not separating the date and volume values correctly. Show the value of `separated`.

Comment: @BartM I don't think he's trying to parse the date, he expects it to be a volume value.

Comment: @BartM you are correct....im trying to keep the date as a string and convert the volume only to float

Comment: @Barmar the values of 'seperated' have the all the dates one after another and then all volume values one after another and the dates and volume values are separated by "&&"

Comment: Don't describe it, SHOW it. Paste it into the question.

Comment: Use `print(volumelst)` to see what you're getting.

Comment: @AlhikelsMixjwlw - in this case volumelst[i] is not what you think it is. But it's hard to tell without looking at the data. I would print(volumelst) to understand what's there - and then think why this is a date string and not a string that could be directly interpreted as a number.

Comment: its weird because it is working perfectly on jupyter but not on idle

Comment: yeah in volumelst there are some dates which arent supposed to be there...i guess there's an error in how the file is being viewed in idle